# ajax multiple file upload with php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, image, file-upload

Hey I am uploading files to a chosen folder and right now I have the ability to select and upload just one file.  I know how to handle multiple files in php but I am not sure how to send all of the files over through AJAX. Thanks for any help you can offer

AJAX

```
 function submitForm() {
            console.log("submit event");
            var fd = new FormData(document.getElementById("fileinfo"));
            fd.append("label", "sound");
            fd.append('label', document.getElementById('selected_folder').value);
            $.ajax({
              url: "upload.php",
              type: "POST",
              data: fd,
              enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
              processData: false,  // tell jQuery not to process the data
              contentType: false   // tell jQuery not to set contentType
            }).done(function( data ) {
                console.log("PHP Output:");
                console.log( data );
                alert("upload success!")
            });
            return false;
        }
```

PHP

```
<?php
if ($_POST["label"]) {
    $subfolder = $_POST["label"];
}


$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < (10000*1024))
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts)) {
    if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) {
         // echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
    } else {
        $filename = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
        echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
        echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
        echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
        echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";



        if (file_exists("uploaded/".$subfolder .'/'. $filename)) {
            //already exists 
        } else {
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
            "uploaded/".$subfolder .'/'. $filename);
            // "Stored in: " . "uploaded/".$subfolder .'/'. $filename;
        }
    }
} else {
    echo "Invalid file";
}
?>
```

Comment: Is the element returned from this `document.getElementById("fileinfo")` a `form`? If not, it should be.

Comment: Here `fileinfo` is id of the form right? It should.

Comment: Nick Did you try with answer?

Comment: wow thanks guys this is perfect! i am in calc class right now but i will definitely try this when i get home. I have a php file that would work perfectly with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass multiple files using form data as below

**HTML**

```
<input id="fuDocument" type="file" accept="image/*" multiple="multiple" />
```

**JS**

```
var fd = new FormData();
var files = $("#fuDocument").get(0).files; // this is my file input in which We can select multiple files.
fd.append("label", "sound");

for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    fd.append("UploadedImage" + i, files[i]);
}

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'Url',
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    data: fd,
    success: function (e) {
        alert("success");                    
    }        
 })
```

Now pass `fd` object in you ajax call it is working with my code

Comment: didi you have a php example that i would be able to run next to this?

Comment: @NickGarver Sorry but I don't have pretty much knowledge of PHP I can do this with Asp.net.

Comment: Thanks you for your code, I have implemented the ajax inside the loop. so  how can I clear form data before append the new file?

Comment: @Samphors I could not understood what you exactly want to do

Answer (score 3):

First you have to use "multiple" attribute with input tag.
Like

```
<input id="fileUpload" type="file" accept="image/*" name="my_file[]" multiple />
```

Then in Javascript onChange function -

```
        var data = new FormData();
        var imgData = document.getElementById('fileUpload'); 

        for (var i = 0; i < imgData.files.length; i++) {                                 
             data.append('my_file[]', imgData.files[i], imgData.files[i].name);
        } 

       //now call ajax
       $.ajax({
          url: "upload.php",
          type: "POST",
          data: data,
          enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
          processData: false,  // tell jQuery not to process the data
          contentType: false   // tell jQuery not to set contentType
        }).done(function( data ) {
            console.log("PHP Output:");
            console.log( data );
            alert("upload success!")
        });
```

And your file will be uploaded