# how can I read FormData file in php?

Tags: php, jquery, forms, multipartform-data

I have an ajax formdata

```
<form id="form" action="index.php?id=upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <input id="files" multiple="true" name="files[]" type="file" />

</form>
```

I want send this form via dataform sequently.

So I create a loop jn jquery to read each file, So per file I have this:

```
var data = new FormData();
        data.append(file.name, file);

        $.ajax({
            url: 'index.php?id=upload',
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData:false,
            data: data,
            fileName:'files',
```

in php code when I print `var_dumb($_FILES)` I get this result:

> names:"array(1) {  ["8_modem_pool_with_small_and_big_jpg"]=>
>   array(5) {    ["name"]=>    string(35) "8 modem pool with small
>   and big.jpg"    ["type"]=>    string(10) "image/jpeg"
>   ["tmp_name"]=>    string(24) "F:\xampp\tmp\php268B.tmp\"
>   ["error"]=>   int(0)   ["size"]=>    int(99790)
>   }}

how can I get `$_FILES` value in server side?
I try

```
if(isset($_FILES["files"]))
        {
```

and

```
if(isset($_FILES["file"]))
        {
```

but none of them not works.

**-------EDIT-------------**

thanks for answers. but them are not my answer.

in php when I use

```
$_FILES["files"]
```

Iget this error:

> Undefined index

But I can print values by this code:

```
foreach($_FILES as $index => $file) {
 move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'],$target.$file['name']); 
}
```

I hope you underestand me....

I want something like this:

```
if(isset($_FILES["files"]))
{
   //do action for single file
   // do action for array file
}
```

lastest code works for normal form,But not work for formdata.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35086065/ajax-multiple-file-upload-with-php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try loop through this 3 level associate array with a `for` loop:

```
if(isset($_FILES['8_modem_pool_with_small_and_big_jpg'])){
    for($i=0;$i < count($_FILES['8_modem_pool_with_small_and_big_jpg']['name']);$i++){
        //Do whatever with the file:
        echo $_FILES['8_modem_pool_with_small_and_big_jpg']['name'][$i];
        echo $_FILES['8_modem_pool_with_small_and_big_jpg']['type'][$i];
        echo $_FILES['8_modem_pool_with_small_and_big_jpg']['tmp_name'][$i];
    }
}
```

Comment: my problem is `$_FILES['files']` ...it return 'Undefined index' error

Comment: @elize did you try `$_FILES['8_modem_pool_with_small_and_big_jpg']` ?

Comment: thanks. your comment is my answer. for custom name I do this and works now. `data.append('files',file);`

Answer (score 0):

try the following:

```
move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['names']['8_modem_pool_with_small_and_big_jpg']['tmp_name'], $target);//target is the new file location and name
```

for multiple files use a loop

```
foreach($_FILES['names'] as $index => $file) {
     $target = '/img/'.$file['name']
     move_uploaded_file( $file['tmp_name'], $target);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what values you want. All of them are visible in the array.

If you want the name you can use

```
$_FILES['names']['8_modem_pool_with_small_and_big_jpg']['tmp_name']
```

To store the file to a specific location you can use

```
move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['names']['8_modem_pool_with_small_and_big_jpg']['tmp_name'], $myFile);
```