# Ajax send array and Image in same request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I want to make an ajax call that sends both JSON and file data to my PHP backend.  This is my ajax call currently:

```
    $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: jsonData,
    url: 'xxx.php',
    cache: false,
    success: function(data) { 
        //removed for example
    }
});
```

The data(jsonData) is a JSON array that also holds the input from a file select as well(I am assuming this is wrong due to the type mismatch).  I tried using `contentType: false`, and `processData: false`, but when I try to access `$_POST` data in PHP there is nothing there.  The data I am passing does not come from a form and there is quite a bit of it so I do not want to use `FormData` and append it to that object.  I am hoping i will not have to make two ajax calls to accomplish this.

Comment: Is this helping? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10899384/uploading-both-data-and-files-in-one-form-using-ajax

Comment: `var jsonData = new FormData(document.getElementById("yourFormID"));` u can use FormData for getting input and files

Comment: now u have few valid solutions, try it

Comment: I do not have a form @devpro but i will try appending my current data to a formdata object

Comment: yes, just append the data in `FormData()`

Comment: Will this work if one of my values is a json object?

Comment: no needed, u can use <form> and hidden input for your data

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send data along with any file than you can use [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects) object.

*Send your `jsonData` as like that:*

```
var jsonData = new FormData(document.getElementById("yourFormID"));
```

*Than in PHP, you can check your data and file as:*

```
<?php
print_r($_POST); // will return all data
print_r($_FILES); // will return your file
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Using [formdata](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/FormData) instead of normal serialized json

Here's an example:

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append("KEY", "VALUE");
formData.append("file", document.getElementById("fileinputID").files[0]);
```

then in your ajax

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "YOUR URL",
    data: formData,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (response) {
       CallBack(response, ExtraData);
    },
    error: function () {
              alert("Error Posting Data");
          }
    });
```

Comment: Will this work if one of my values is also a JSON object?

Comment: no, you will get them as a normal POST form, you could do print_r($_POST) to check the values.

On the other hand, you can use FormData to add Json. for example:

formData.append("JSON", YOUR_JSON_OBJ");

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this also

You can visit this answer also 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/35086265/2798643

**HTML**

```
<input id="fuDocument" type="file" accept="image/*" multiple="multiple" />
```

**JS**

```
var fd = new FormData();
var files = $("#fuDocument").get(0).files; // this is my file input in which We can select multiple files.
fd.append("kay", "value"); //As the same way you can append more fields

for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    fd.append("UploadedImage" + i, files[i]);
}

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'Url',
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    data: fd,
    success: function (e) {
        alert("success");                    
    }        
 })
```